# Finding the correlation for a function minimization

Tags: python, minimize

I need to minimize a function in Python and then find the correlation between its variable (let's say f(x,y)). I tried using scipy.optimize.minimize with

```
res = minimize (f,x0,method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

and it is minimized but I can't get the correlation between x,y. There is a way to do this using this package? Or there is another better way? (i do not need to do a fit on some points, I need just to find the minimum of the function)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the correlation between x,y'? How should this be calculated?

Comment: @barny Correlation is a relation between 2 variables. For example if it is a positive correlation between them, and x is increasing with dx then y will also increase with dy, where dx and dy are related by this correlation. The formula it's not always that easy as I know, I was wondering if there is some built in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find the minimum point of a function `f`, within the domain `x0`, you can simply use `scipy.optimize.fmin`. setting the disp arg in this function will return the convergence message. 
if you are after the regression between `x0` and `f`, then use scipy `scipy.stats.linregress`.
if you want to calculate the correlation between the solution of the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function and the original `f`, then you can use `scipy.signal.correlate`

Comment: I don't want to calculate the correlation between the functions. So i need to plot a gaussian, and to vary the median and standard deviation to minimize the gaussian for some given constants. I want to see the correlation between median and standard deviation. Can I still do that using scipy.signal.correlate?

Comment: in general correlate() takes in two vectors, and returns a single value representing their difference (or shift). median and s.d. of a data set are singular values so their correlation will simply be their difference. calculate median and sd of the original dataset, then do the same for returned value of minimize(f, x0).x   (this is where the solution array is stored), and then take the difference of the two